# Calculating charge of a sphere

Tags: electrostatics

Consider a sphere with radius $r_0$which is homogeneously charged with charge density

$\rho(r)=\begin{cases} \rho_0 & r\leq r_0 \\ 0 & r > r_0\end{cases} \tag{1}$

if $Q_0$ is the total charge of the sphere, we get

$\rho_0 = \frac{Q_0}{V}=\frac{4Q_0}{3 \pi r_0^3} \tag{2}$

so inside the sphere we have the constant charge density $\rho_0$ and outside we don't have any charge density.

I now want to properly calculate $Q(r)=\int_{r'\leq r}\rho(r' ) dV'$

I do get the whole gist of it and my intuition about the problem is clear - I just noticed I'm not satisfied with how I mathematically argue.

$Q(r)=\int_{r'\leq r}\rho(r' ) dV' = \int_0^r dr' r'^2 \rho(r') \int_0^{2\pi}d\varphi \int_0^\pi \sin(\vartheta) d\vartheta=4\pi\int_0^r dr' r'^2 \rho(r') \tag{3}$

so far, so good. The next step is basically to distinguish between inside/on the sphere and outside. And exactly that's my problem. We'd find

$ = \begin{cases}4\pi \int_0^r dr' r^{'2}\rho_0 & r\leq r_0 \\ Q_0 & r > r_0\end{cases}\tag{4}$

all that makes, physically, perfect sense but I don't see how we mathematically get from (3) to (4). We obviously have a discontinuity in the integrand at $r=r_0$ because of $\rho(r)$.

We still have a proper integral though, so we just split it:

$4\pi\int_0^r dr' r'^2 \rho(r') = 4\pi\int_0^{r_0} dr' r'^2 \underbrace{\rho(r')}_{\rho_0} + 4\pi\int_{r_0}^r dr' r'^2 \underbrace{\rho(r')}_{0}$

but that bviously doesn't work. So how do we mathematically, as pedantically as possible, get from (3) to (4)? What I mean is: I want to start at (1) and get to (4) without once arguing in a physical sense.

Comment: Also the calculation you perform for $\rho_0$ is incorrect, it'll be $$\rho_0 = \frac{3Q_0}{4\pi R^3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r<r_0$ than you need simply evaluate the integral. When $r > r_0$ you have to split integral into two parts: from $0$ to $r_0$ and from $r_0$ to $r$, since the integrand is represented in these two regions by different functions. Thus, for $r>r_0$:
$$\int_0^rdr'r'^2 = \int_0^{r_0}dr'r'^2 + \int_{r_0}^rdr'r'^2.$$
The first of these integrals gives you charge $Q_0$, whereas the second is zero.